# How can I Regex filename with exactly 1 underscores in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, filenames

I need to match if filenames have exactly 1 underscores. For example:

```
Prof. Leonel Messi_300001.pdf    ->  true
Christiano Ronaldo_200031.xlsx    ->  true
Eden Hazard_3322.pdf       ->  true
John Terry.pdf    ->  false
100023.xlsx    ->  false
300022_Fernando Torres.pdf       ->  false
```

So the sample : `name_id.extnames`

Note : name is string and id is number

I try like this : `[a-zA-Z\d]+_[0-9\d]`

Is my regex correct?

Comment: `0-9` is redundant with `\d` and you have no quantifier after the second class either so it will only match a single digit. This regex will also match stuff that doesn't have an extension, which may or may not be what you want. Either way, I usually build regexes on a site for that purpose, like https://regex101.com/

Comment: What about `_hello.txt` - that's one underscore. Should it pass or fail?

Comment: Why regex? `.split("_").length <= 2`

Comment: @Andreas See the note and sample above

Comment: @slebetman Fail. See the sample

Comment: _"How can I Regex filename with exactly 1 underscores"_, _"I need to match if filenames have exactly 1 underscores"_ - Is possible with `.split()`. Only later in the code and from a _"note"_ it gets "clear" that you actually want to match the whole filename against a pattern that not only checks for underscores.

Answer (score 1):

As the filename will be name_id.extension, as `name` string or space `[a-z\s]+?` then underscore `_`, then the id is a number `[0-9]+?`, then the dot, as dot is a special character you need to scape it with backslash `\.`, then the extension name with `[a-z]+`

```js
const checkFileName = (fileName) => {
  const result = /[a-z\s]+?_\d+?\.[a-z]+/i.test(fileName);
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}

checkFileName('Prof. Leonel Messi_300001.pdf')
checkFileName('Christiano Ronaldo_200031.xlsx')
checkFileName('Eden Hazard_3322.pdf')
checkFileName('John Terry.pdf')
checkFileName('100023.xlsx')
checkFileName('300022_Fernando Torres.pdf')
```

Answer (score 1):

##### Regex

My try with separate groups for

- `name`: Can contain anything. Last `_` occurrence should be the end
- `id`: Can contain only numbers. Last `_` occurrence should be the start
- `ext`: Before last `.`. Can only contain `a-z` and should be more than one character.

```
/^(?<name>.+)\_(?<id>\d+)\.(?<ext>[a-z]+)/g
```

[Regex 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CHdMPP/1)

##### JS

```
const fileName = "Lionel Messi_300001.pdf"

const r = /^(?<name>.+)\_(?<id>\d+)\.(?<ext>[a-z]+)/g

const fileNameMatch = r.test(fileName)

if (fileNameMatch) {
    r.lastIndex = 0
    console.log(r.exec(fileName).groups)
}
```

See [CodePen](https://codepen.io/kiran589/pen/zYWjJeY)

Answer (score 0):

```
[a-zA-Z]+_[0-9\d]+
```

or

```
[a-zA-Z]+_[\d]+
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `^...$` to match the line. Then just try to search a group before `_` which doesn't have `_`, and the group after, without `_`.

```
^(?<before>[^_]*)_(?<after>[^_]*)\.\w+$
```

https://regex101.com/r/ZrA7B1/1